# How do I get the events of a resource calendar via a service account (Google Calendar API)?

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

I wrote a Node/Express application and want to access the events from a resource calendar via a service account.
It works fine when I use my personal calendar but with resource calendars it gives me a blank page.

That's what I have to far. What do I have to change to make it work?

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

let {google} = require('googleapis');
const calendar = google.calendar('v3');

const port = 3000;
const key = require('./credentials.json');

const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    key.client_email,
    null,
    key.private_key,
    [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar' ],
    null
);

jwtClient.authorize(function(err) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Authorization worked!");
    }
});

const calendarID = 'XXXXX@resource.calendar.google.com';

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    calendar.events.list({
        auth: jwtClient,
        calendarId: calendarID,
        timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
        maxResults: 2,
        singleEvents: true,
        orderBy: 'startTime'
    }, function(err, resp) {
        res.json(resp);
    });

});

app.listen(port, function(err){
    if (!err) {
        console.log("XXXXX is running on port", port);
    } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service accounts work like regular accounts - they have their own permissions, and cannot access a calendar's information unless they have explicitly been given access to it.

In order to overcome this issue you can:

1. Share the calendar to your Service Account. You simply have to share it as you would with any regular user, albeit assigning the Service Account's e-mail.
2. Use [Domain-Wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) in case you are using G Suite (not a regular/consumer account). You can learn more in the provided hyperlink. This feature allows you to "impersonate" another user of the domain, which will allow you not only to retrieve the events but also modify the calendar and events as you please, as you would have "owner" rights over it.

Comment: Can I access the events of the resource calendar with the same calendar.events.list() method I use above?